# Change font color in html VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to change the color even with all i tried.

```
    For Each emailAdress In emailInformation
        Set colLines = emailInformation(emailAdress)
        sBodyInfo = ""
        For Each line In colLines
            sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & _
                          "Appareil : " & line.appareil & vbCrLf & _
                          "Site : " & line.site & vbCrLf & _
```

I just want to change "SITE" color in red.

Everytime I try something, it shows the tags appearing in the email like it's a string!

Comment: What is the format of the message?  HTML, plain text, or rich text ?

Comment: I have no idea. Seems like plain text  " ByVal sBody As String  " @TimWilliams

Comment: A bit more code would be helpful here - there's nothing in what you posted which we could use as a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are working on creating an email, then you may have a `Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem` defined upper in your code.
Maybe this is what you are actually trying to do:

```
 For Each emailAdress In emailInformation
        Set colLines = emailInformation(emailAdress)
        sBodyInfo = ""
        For Each line In colLines
            sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & _
                          "Appareil : " & line.appareil & vbCrLf & _
                          "<p style=""color:#FF0000"">Site : " & line.site & "</p>"
```

and then set the `.HTMLBody` attribute of your `objMail` object instead of just `.Body`.

Hope this helps